# Xcode: How to rotate a Slider or Progress view without deforming them

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am just trying to have a `vertical slider` and `progressBar` in my iPhone app, but every time I try to transform them to rotate them 90 degrees, they either disappear or stretch. Is there a way to prevent this? All I want to happen is for the slider and progress bar to appear vertical but stay the same size and have the same appearance.

Addition:

I found the code on here how to rotate:

```
    define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
    [self.progressView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle))];
```

I am creating the `slider` and `progress view` in the `stoyboard`, linking it to variables I've declared in the `ViewController.m`. As the "angle" increases the `progress ba`r and the `slider` increasingly stretch. In the end when I rotate 90 the `progress bar` disappears and the `slider` appears just to be a thumb image but no `slider bar`.

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Create a transformation with just the rotation
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));

    //Now apply our scale
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 2, 2);

    //Now set the transform on the object to the combined rotation/scale transform.
    [self.shield2 setTransform: transform];

    CGAffineTransform sliderRotation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    sliderRotation = CGAffineTransformRotate(sliderRotation, -DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(89));

    self.shield.transform = sliderRotation;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you rotate the slider? It sounds like a problem with positioning/sizing the view, rather than with the transform.

Comment: Post the code that creates the transform and applies it to the view.

Comment: Is autolayout enabled for your storyboard?

Comment: @robmayoff that fixed it, thank you. Still new at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto layout doesn't play well with transforms. Either disable auto layout or remove any constraints between the transformed controls and other views and position the controls “by hand”.

Comment: Saved my bacon! I was getting so frustrated over this